# Generate normal noise column-wise using numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix `A` in which the signals are contained along the columns, I want to generate a noise matrix in which each **column contains Gaussian normal noise** (mean = 0, std = 1).

[image]

**Wrong Logic Code:**

I can do something like below but in that case the condition `mean = 0` would be true for the whole matrix and not just for the columns.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]]
            )

# Generate Gaussian noise with mean 0 and std deviation 1
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=A.shape)
```

**PS:** Need to be performance optimized (avoid for-loops)

Comment: The goal in unclear, do you want to add a fixed noise per column? or a fully random noise per cell? You code seems correct.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Do you want the entries to be generated from a N(0,1) variable, or do you want to enforce strict mean=0 and std=1 on each column?

Comment: @mozway: Each column of the `noise matrix` should contain random Gaussian noise. The mean of the noise along each given column should be zero. In my given code, the mean would be zero across the whole matrix (not just a single column).  Furthermore, each column should have different noise (gaussian, mean = 0, std = 1).

Comment: @Learningisamess: I want to enforce mean=0 and std=1 on each column

Comment: "*Each column of the noise matrix should contain random Gaussian noise*" / "*The mean of the noise along each given column should be zero.*" and "*each column should have different noise*" is contradictory. Can you give a numerical example?

Comment: Furthermore "the mean of each column is zero" implies "the mean of the whole matrix is zero"

Comment: @mozway: but the mean `zero` of the whole noise matrix does not imply that the mean of each column is zero.  If my whole matrix fulfills the condition that `mean = 0` then it may happen that some columns are more influenced by negative values and others by more positive values. Example of columns fullfilling N(0, 1): Col-1 `{ -0.31415927, 0.59265359, 1.57079633, -1.04719755, -0.52359878, 0.78539816, -1.25663706, -0.20943951, 0.20943951, 0.26179939}`...and Col-2: `{-0.10274994, 1.02756436, -0.48863684, -1.26004699, 0.53629392, 0.20493729, -0.60819871, 1.04328647, 0.77849388, -0.82337849 }`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to enforce that the mean of each column is 0, and their std is one:

```py
noise = (noise - noise.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)) / noise.std(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Mean and std of the whole matrix will be (1,0) fyi: addition of means, and addition of variances between independent columns.

Comment: I edited your code for clarity since OP wants colwise mean=0 and std=1 for the _`noise`_ array. Can you explain what you mean by the sentence after your code, _"addition of means, and addition of variances..._"

Comment: Thanks for the variable rename @pho, indeed the transformation is only meant for the noise contribution. I will elaborate later on the last sentence.